# Horizontal scrolling in mobile view in html/css

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am working on a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ktw74hp4/24/embedded/result/) in which I want to **horizontally scroll** the contents in a **mobile view**.

At this moment in a desktop view, they are aligned in a straight line as shown below:

[image]

I want the above contents to scroll in a mobile view.

The CSS codes which I have used in order to align the contents in a straight line in a desktop view are:

```
.images {
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 1rem;


}

.images > div {
      flex-basis: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
.images img {
  max-width:100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what CSS codes I should add in the fiddle so that the  contents present in the above **screenshot scroll in a mobile view**. I tried with `overflow: scroll and white-space: nowrap` but somehow I wasn't able to scroll the contents in mobile view.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding flex none to the divs so that their size is preserved and a media query where you want desktop to start.

```
.images {
    display: flex;
    align-items:center;
    background-color: #eee;
    padding: 1rem;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

.images > div {
    flex: none;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

.images img {
    max-width:100%;
    width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 960px) {

  .images {
     overflow-x: visible;
  }

  .images > div {
    flex-basis: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
   }
}
```

Comment: I want the horizontal scroll to come in the mobile view. At this moment, it is showing in the desktop view with your css codes.

Comment: @user5447339 then use the `@media` query.

Comment: @Rawrplus  Like in the desktop view, I want to the look the same as it is present in the fiddle. For the mobile view, `@media screen and (max-width: 767px){
.images{
;
}
}`, what code do I need to add ? Sorry I am not good with media queries.

Comment: Updated example with media query

Comment: @dbenmore I have accepted your answer. I will let you know if I have any question related to that.

Comment: @dbenmore Hi, I have a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50499051/horizontal-scrolling-of-square-boxes-in-a-mobile-view-in-html-css) I am wondering if you can help me out.

Answer (score 2):

You can add this div to your code to **scroll** **horizontally.**
In image 1 you can add your image.(That is for example only)

```css
.container {
 width: 30em;
 overflow-x: auto;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>Image 1</td>
   <td>Image 2</td>
   <td>Image 3</td>
   <td>Image 4</td>
   <td>Image 5</td>
   <td>Image 6</td>
                        <td>Image 1</td>
   <td>Image 2</td>
   <td>Image 3</td>
   <td>Image 4</td>
   <td>Image 5</td>
   <td>Image 6</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For any page horizontal scroll, you can fix it by adding this snippets

```
@media screen and (max-width:767px) {
html, body {overflow-x: hidden;}
}
```