# How to horizontal scroll square boxes in a mobile view in html/css?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, horizontal-scrolling

I have a website which looks perfect on the desktop view. I have created the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/92jks6fn/embedded/result/) as well so that its easy to make changes.

The snippets of CSS codes which I have used in order to align the squares in a row are:

```
.squares {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items:center;
  padding: 1rem;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.squares .square {
    width: 13%;
    text-align: center;
    height: 150px;
    padding-top: 1%;
    padding-left: 1%;
    padding-right: 1%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: rgb(145, 147, 150);
    border-radius: 10px;
   }
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what CSS codes I should add [here](http://ferhan.ferohost.com/style.css) or change so that I am able to **horizontally scroll** the square boxes **in a mobile view** similar to the following screenshot:

[image]

At this moment, in the **mobile view** it is fit to the screen but **not scrolling horizontally**.

Answer (score 2):

Try also changing:

```
.squares{
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
.squares .square{
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

This prevents the squares from going to the second line.

Comment: I tried that but I am not able to achieve the desired screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following code as an example:

**CSS**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {

    .squares {
        overflow-x: scroll;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        height: 200px;
        white-space:nowrap
    }

    .squares .square {
        width: 30%;
        text-align: center;
        height: 150px;
        display:inline-block; /* Added */
        margin-bottom: 11%;
        /*padding-top: 1%;
        padding-left: 1%;
        padding-right: 1%;*/
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 3px;
        border-color: rgb(145,147,150);
        border-radius: 10px;
    }

}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="squares">
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I´m testing it and it works. Did you copied the css and the html?

Comment: Sure take your time.

Comment: Can you use my example as your base html/css?

Comment: Ok after that ?

Comment: I do have a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e6gkejud/2/embedded/) scrolling in mobile view but I want the scrolling to be totally gone in the desktop view.

Comment: Is there any way we can do that ?